# $("#my-div").css("height", $(window).outerHeight() + "px"); works with window.resize() but not $(window).load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As the title says, I'm trying to set the height of my div equal to the height of my viewport, but it only seems to proc when I resize the window and not when the page loads. The full code looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function() { resize_div(); });
window.onresize = function(event) { resize_div(); };

function resize_div() {
  $("#my-div").css("height", ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#menu").outerHeight()) + "px");
}
```

Why would it work on the window resize but now on window load? Thanks in advance for your help.

### Update

Here are some other things that do not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  resize_div();
});
window.onload = function(event) { resize_div(); };
$("#my-div").on("load", function() { resize_div(); });
setTimeout(resize_div(), 3000); # this was put inside $(document).ready()
```

### Update 2

I added alerts to `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` and both alerts were fired off before the timeline I'm embedding was loaded. So I think this might be an issue that's outside the scope of how I've phrased my question. The app I'm using - Shiny, which is sort of like Python's Flask module - is presumably loading the webpage and then dynamically injecting the divs into the body of the web page, which is why the function isn't working properly. However, adding a `console.log` to `resize_div` didn't result in any output either, so I don't think it's just an issue of the div not being present right away.

Comment: add some delay and it will work then.. $(window).load(function() { resize_div(); }); changed it to $(window).load(function() { settimeout(resize_div,99) });

Comment: Can you create live demo on StackSnippet or jsfiddle

Comment: @razahassank **Can never trust delays**

Comment: @Tushar would the full website suffice? It can be found [here](45.55.233.87/shiny/timelinejs/).

Comment: `window.onresize(...)` <-- that syntax is wrong... I am not sure how that is working

Comment: @epascarello Oops, you're right. That's a typo in the question code. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I tested your code and its working fine. I think the javascript is not responding in your browser.Run this code in another browser.

Comment: @smaty Interesting.. I'm currently developing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in Firefox 42.0, which is where it's not working. So, based on your suggestion, I went back to my Mac OSX in Safari and tested there and it still didn't work. What is your environment in which is worked?

Comment: I tested this in Windows 10 on google chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this, this is working for me.

```js
$(function(){
  resize_div();
  window.onresize = function(event) { resize_div(); };
});


function resize_div() {
  alert(0);
  $("#my-div").css("height", ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#menu").outerHeight()) + "px");
  $("#my-div").css("background-color","yellow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div">adfggfgsdgsfdgsfhfg</div>
<div id="menu" style="height:100px;">MenuDiv</div>
```

Comment: I had a lot of hope that that was going to work, but it did not. Again, resizing the window causes the function to run, but it doesn't run without any sort of trigger.

Comment: i think this run on both event when resize and load i put alert on my function that fire both time please run again.

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya I believe your code achieves what I'm asking it to achieve, with the exception of my situation. Please see my update to the question as after some troubleshooting, I think the problem lies deeper than my question originally let on.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer to close out this question. I think the issue I'm having is outside the scope of this question and your response does work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code definitely works (I'm on ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Firefox 42 myself!) and here is the proof of the pudding:

```js
$(window).load(function() { console.log('window.load'); resize_div(); });

$(document).ready(function() { console.log('document.ready'); resize_div(); });

window.onresize = function(event) { resize_div(); }

function resize_div() {
  $("#my-div").css("height", ($(window).outerHeight() - $("#menu").outerHeight()) + "px");
  console.log("resize_div called");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu" style="height:100px;width:300px;background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<div id="my-div" style="background-color:brown;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've called the `resize_div()` in both $(document).ready() and $(window).load. I've placed `console.log` statements at all three places: the above events and inside the `resize_div()`, as you can see all the statements get printed. Now, the particular issue on your end could be anything:

- Maybe you are using a modified/tainted version of jQuery.
- Maybe the event fires, but the output is not what you wanted.
- Maybe there is an error in some other part in your script.

By console logging the problematic parts, I'm sure you will identify the troubling code in your app. Best of luck!